# Is it possible for you to get Euclidean norm from city block distance by moving a infinitesimal length every step?

Tags: metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry

So I know the formal definition of taxicab norm is ${\displaystyle \left\|\mathbf {x} \right\|:=\sum _{i=1}^{n}\left|x_{i}\right|}$, yet this time I would like to go from the definition that in taxicab metric you're constrained to move on along a grid (which only allows left/right/upward/downward movements). What I'm wondering is why can't you get Euclidean metric simply by making the grid's separation infinitesimal small?

Like if you `let d=the separation of the grid`, which meant the set of all possible points $\mathbb{S}=\{(x*d, y*d) \mid x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, and your metric will be the travel path length given the path could only travel within the set $\|x\|=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (m_{i+1, \,x}-m_{i,\,x}+m_{i+1, \,y}-m_{i,\,y})$ where $m_i$ is the i-th step of your path and $m_i\in\mathbb{S}$. With such definition, shouldn't it meant that if we $\lim_{d\to 0}$ we would essentially get Euclidean space as $\lim_{d\to0}\mathbb{S}=\mathbb{R}$. And one possible path that you could taken from origin to a certain point would be the straight line connecting those two points.

But still it seems weird (like even I'm not fully convinced), since $\forall d\in\mathbb{R}^+$ shouldn't the travel path length all sums to the same number? As since $\|x\|=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (m_{i+1, \,x}-m_{i,\,x}+m_{i+1, \,y}-m_{i,\,y})=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (m_{i+1, \,x}-m_{i,\,x})\right)+\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (m_{i+1, \,y}-m_{i,\,y})\right)=$ horizontal difference + vertical difference.

So which part of my analogy is incorrect?  I feel like my assumption that $\lim_{d\to0}\mathbb{S}=\mathbb{R}$ might missed something, but I'm not sure where did I got wrong?

Comment: No, see the [staircase paradox](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiagonalParadox.html). If it worked we could prove that that the diagional of a square is twice its side, and that =4 (by inscribing staircases into a circle). The paradox [goes back to Lebesgue](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/11241/55) and is probably older. The arclength is not continuous under uniform convergence of curves, so the limit of lengths need not be the length of the limit, you need stronger convergence for that.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it: no matter how small you make the increments, your total distance in each direction is unchanged, so the taxicab distance is the same.

The [p norm decreases in $p$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/P-Norm_of_Real_Sequence_is_Strictly_Decreasing_Function_of_P) so relative to moving along a grid, you will travel less distance moving along the diagonal, which is what the Euclidean metric represents.